# Trapdoors of Lattices: SampleD and SamplePre

Tags: lattice-crypto

In [Trapdoors for Hard Lattices and New Cryptographic Constructions](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vinodv/trapcvp.pdf) by Gentry et. al, they discuss SamplePre and in [Trapdoors for Lattices: Simpler, Tighter, Faster, Smaller](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2012/72370695/72370695.pdf) by Micciancio et.al, they discuss SampleD.

But still, I cannot understand whether the functionality id same or different. Can you explain?

Comment: Welcome to cryptography. Could you point where you stuck by writing down into your question?

Comment: I want to know whether these two functions are identical or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they aren't the same. One of them maps 4 values to a single value, the other maps 2 values to a single value.

But yes, both functions have some similarities. Both compute the inverse of a known function witch can be computed only because a trapdoor is given (t in SamplePre and R in SampleD). We can use SampleD to create different SamplePre functions changing the parameters creating this way different trapdoor schemes.

Comment: What would be the output of both functions? and relation to the inputs? Is there any source I can refer?